# How to customize keybinds

Tags: c#, key-bindings

I'm trying to find a way to customize the keybinds in my program. I'd like to make something like the image below
[image]

How could I go about doing this? Is it just best to make a list of buttons and apply them to an int in my settings?

Answer (score -1):

As an option - you can create a custom cotrol where you will define everything you need